# HoloLens App suddenly doesn't start anymore! Error: "Failed to load game Assembly"

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I have tried to implement the Mixed Reality Toolkit and compiled the Spatial Mapping example. It already worked but suddenly it shows (even when trying to run simple projects with only a Light and a Main Camera) a window with "Failed to load game assembly!" And a button to submit. Then it closes the app again. Error:

```
[0.249800 / 0.261977] - Initializing Unity runtime
Loading native plugins
  Loading AudioPluginMsHRTF.dll
"OpenCV-HoloLens.exe" (Win32): "U:\Users\DefaultAccount\AppData\Local\DevelopmentFiles\Template3DVS.Debug_Win32.niklas.baumgartner\AudioPluginMsHRTF.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"OpenCV-HoloLens.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\HrtfApo.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"OpenCV-HoloLens.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\execmodelproxy.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
Exception thrown at 0x777BF2B2 in OpenCV-HoloLens.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Cn::XH at memory location 0x018FE4AC.
onecoreuap\windows\moderncore\inputv2\inputhost\components\cursor\client\cursorclient.cpp(43)\InputHost.dll!6F37AB33: (caller: 6F37ACAC) ReturnHr(1) tid(c28) 87B20809 onecoreuap\windows\moderncore\inputv2\inputhost\components\cursor\client\cursorclient.cpp(75)\InputHost.dll!6F37ACC3: (caller: 6F34959D) ReturnHr(2) tid(c28) 87B20809 "OpenCV-HoloLens.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\UiaManager.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"OpenCV-HoloLens.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Core.TextInput.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
[0.001837 / 0.437985] - AppCallbacks::SetCoreWindowEvents
"OpenCV-HoloLens.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Perception.Stub.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"OpenCV-HoloLens.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Mirage.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
wil(439)\Windows.Mirage.dll!6F7FC73F: (caller: 6F7FC564) ReturnHr(1) tid(7cc) 80070005 Access is denied.
"OpenCV-HoloLens.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\d3d10warp.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"OpenCV-HoloLens.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\ResourcePolicyClient.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"OpenCV-HoloLens.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\ResourcePolicyClient.dll" wurde entladen.
[0.142645 / 0.581254] - AppCallbacks::InitializeD3DWindow
"OpenCV-HoloLens.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
Module information:
 Built with Compiler Ver '191326128'
 Built from '2018.3/release' branch
 Version is '2018.3.9f1 (947e1ea5aa8d)'
 Debug build
 Application type 'D3D'
"OpenCV-HoloLens.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Devices.Enumeration.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"OpenCV-HoloLens.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\deviceassociation.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
[0.624872 / 0.624872] - OnCoreWindowSizeChanged event (0.00, 0.00, 853.33, 480.00), m_Initialized=False.
[0.002010 / 0.626882] - OnActivated event.
[0.007115 / 0.633997] - OnVisibilityChanged event - Visible.
[0.010231 / 0.644227] - OnWindowActivated event - CodeActivated.
 OS 'Windows 10 (10.0.17763)'
Failed to load Game Assembly!
"OpenCV-HoloLens.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\HoloShellRuntime.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"OpenCV-HoloLens.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\capauthz.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
"OpenCV-HoloLens.exe" (Win32): "C:\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll" geladen. PDB-Datei wurde nicht gefunden oder konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
[0.629493 / 1.273720] - OnCoreWindowSizeChanged event (0.00, 0.00, 853.33, 480.00), m_Initialized=False.
[0.024231 / 1.297951] - OnWindowActivated event - Deactivated.
```

First, this problem didn't occur at previous runs from my app and it seems like the project isn't directly responsible for this error.

Build settings:
[image]

Player settings:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why but i tried the following steps:

- Update Unity to 2018.3.10f
- Deleting the Content of the selected output folder

Now it works again, i had it occur 1 time again but i tried the second step and it seemed to remove this problem